# Create a ggplot Split hours minutes and seconds

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to scale my group to show hours, minutes and seconds. I don't know how to set the scale_x_time function. Also, I would like to include lines to delimite  8am and 6pm. Probably this time is not recorded in my dataset. What do you recommend doing?

R code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(viridis)
library(gganimate)

df <- read_csv("Date_Time_outdoor_temp_25_01_2023.csv")
df <- na.omit(df)
df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time)

#df$temperature <- as.numeric(gsub("<f8>$", "", df$temperature)) ####remove celsius sign
df$WeekDay <- factor(df$WeekDay, levels = c("Sunday","Saturday","Friday","Thursday","Wednesday","Tuesday","Monday"))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=WeekDay) ) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Temperature)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Temperature)) +
 #scale_x_time(breaks = hms::hms(hours = seq(0, 24, 2))) + ###here I need help
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_viridis()+
 # geom_vline(xintercept = lubridate::hms(c("08:00:00", "18:00:00")),col = "blue", lwd = 2, lty=2) + ###as well here
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x="", y ="", fill="Temperature", title="") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1,family="Times", face="bold", size=14), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=14),
        strip.text = element_text(size=12, face="bold")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.position="right",
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(
    legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"),
    legend.key.height = unit(4, "cm")
  )

p
```

Sample data:

```r
 df<-structure(list(Time = c("01:28:53", "01:33:53", "01:38:53", "01:43:53", 
"01:48:53", "01:53:53", "01:58:53", "02:03:53", "02:08:53", "02:13:53", 
"02:18:53", "02:23:53", "02:28:53", "02:33:53", "02:38:53", "02:43:53", 
"02:48:53", "02:53:53", "02:58:53", "03:03:53", "03:08:53", "03:13:53", 
"03:18:53", "03:23:53", "03:28:53", "03:33:53", "03:38:53", "03:43:53", 
"03:48:53", "03:53:53", "03:58:53", "04:03:53", "04:08:53", "04:13:53", 
"04:18:53", "04:23:53", "04:28:53", "04:33:53", "04:38:53", "04:43:53", 
"04:48:53", "04:53:53", "04:58:53", "05:03:53", "05:08:53", "05:13:53", 
"05:18:53", "05:23:53", "05:28:53", "05:33:53", "05:38:53", "05:43:53", 
"05:48:53", "05:53:53", "05:58:53", "06:03:53", "06:08:53", "06:13:53", 
"06:18:53", "06:23:53", "06:28:53", "06:33:53", "06:38:53", "06:43:53", 
"06:48:53", "06:53:53", "06:58:53", "07:03:53", "07:08:53", "07:13:53", 
"07:18:53", "07:23:53", "07:28:53", "07:33:53", "07:38:53", "07:43:53", 
"07:48:53", "07:53:53", "07:58:53", "08:03:53", "08:08:53", "08:13:53", 
"08:18:53", "08:23:53", "08:28:53", "08:33:53", "08:38:53", "08:43:53", 
"08:48:53", "08:53:53", "08:58:53", "09:03:53", "09:08:53", "09:13:53", 
"09:18:53", "09:23:53", "09:28:53", "09:33:53", "09:38:53", "09:43:53"
), Temperature = c(22.973, 14.699, 14.029, 14.005, 14.053, 14.388, 
14.364, 14.316, 13.837, 13.885, 14.364, 13.741, 14.196, 14.412, 
14.532, 14.436, 14.364, 14.005, 14.101, 14.196, 14.101, 14.172, 
14.268, 14.819, 14.22, 14.723, 15.034, 14.556, 15.202, 14.484, 
14.148, 14.34, 14.771, 15.249, 14.963, 14.292, 13.933, 14.292, 
14.484, 14.412, 14.532, 14.556, 14.508, 14.436, 14.556, 14.532, 
14.412, 14.34, 14.196, 14.22, 14.196, 14.077, 14.101, 13.981, 
13.885, 13.837, 13.837, 13.5, 13.356, 13.356, 13.091, 12.609, 
12.754, 12.995, 12.56, 11.543, 11.276, 10.959, 10.886, 11.008, 
10.788, 10.739, 10.593, 10.446, 10.495, 10.25, 10.176, 10.274, 
10.078, 10.054, 9.857, 9.833, 9.759, 9.66, 9.488, 9.512, 9.685, 
9.71, 9.759, 9.833, 9.734, 9.636, 9.537, 9.34, 9.216, 9.167, 
8.994, 8.721, 8.646, 8.721), RH = c(54.969, 64.515, 68.844, 69.702, 
70.629, 69.314, 70.229, 70.077, 70.158, 70.482, 70.43, 70.569, 
70.713, 69.951, 69.801, 69.237, 69.338, 69.444, 70.208, 70.713, 
70.752, 71.338, 70.24, 69.913, 70.03, 69.665, 68.018, 67.147, 
67.118, 66.756, 67.942, 67.717, 67.65, 66.602, 66.375, 68.633, 
67.903, 68.287, 65.21, 65.811, 64.486, 65.456, 65.944, 66.515, 
64.167, 62.779, 63.083, 63.365, 64.105, 65.076, 63.164, 63.702, 
63.383, 64.331, 64.929, 65.767, 66.32, 67.766, 68.258, 68.489, 
69.301, 71.178, 70.637, 69.197, 70.458, 74.265, 75.658, 76.838, 
76.988, 76.903, 77.655, 78.304, 78.819, 79.442, 79.316, 79.997, 
80.307, 80.437, 80.421, 80.469, 80.615, 80.718, 80.593, 80.733, 
80.587, 79.998, 80.09, 79.824, 79.672, 79.58, 79.069, 78.912, 
78.237, 78.085, 75.894, 75.112, 74.441, 72.61, 70.807, 69.95), 
    WeekDay = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L), .Label = c("Sunday", "Saturday", "Friday", "Thursday", 
    "Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Monday"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Problematic outcome:

[image]

Comment: Your time is not in a datetime format, so your `as.POSIXct(.)` call fails for me. Are you not getting an error `character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't ignore errors, your call to `as.POSIXct` is failing. Your use of `hms::hms` in the axis is a good start, though you need to apply the same logic to your `Time` column as well. Starting with your `structure` version of `df`:

```r
df$Time <- strsplit(df$Time, ":") |>
  lapply(function(z) as.numeric(rev(z))) |>
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _) |>
   # R >= 4.2.0
  unname() |>
  do.call(hms::hms, args = _)
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ Time       : 'hms' num  01:28:53 01:33:53 01:38:53 01:43:53 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
#  $ Temperature: num  23 14.7 14 14 14.1 ...
#  $ RH         : num  55 64.5 68.8 69.7 70.6 ...
#  $ WeekDay    : Factor w/ 7 levels "Sunday","Saturday",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
```

From here, your plot (with commented-out portions uncommented) works fine.